# Program crashes while destructor calls delete function

Tags: c++, destructor

I am working a large code and the program crashes, when the destructor is called. I am specifying the place, where it fails:

```
Application::~Application()
{
  for ( int blockId=0; blockId< m_noBlocks; blockId++ ) {
    if ( m_blocks[ blockId ] ) {
      delete m_blocks[ blockId ];  //error here
      m_blocks[ blockId ] = NULL;
    }
    if ( m_methods[ blockId ] ) {
      delete m_methods[ blockId ];
      m_methods[ blockId ] = NULL;
    }
  }
}
```

The program crashes exactly at the delete operation mentioned at 'error here'. However, if I comment the line, the program seems to work fine. Could someone throw a light, what could be the possible problem?

Edit:
They are allocated in constructor using `new`. `m_noBlocks` is defined with a value and is not specified here:

```
Application::Application(){
      m_blocks = new ZFSBlock*[m_noBlocks];
      m_methods = new ZFSMethods*[m_noBlocks];

      for ( int blockId=0; blockId< m_noBlocks; blockId++ ) {
        m_methods[ blockId ] = NULL;
        m_blocks[ blockId ] = NULL;
      }
}
```

However, there is actual assignment of `m_methods` and `m_blocks` inside the main part of the code later.

Comment: How where these things allocated?

Comment: Don't use `delete` in C++. Use proper SBRM-style single-responsibility data structures for handling resources.

Comment: Please give us more context: *What is `m_blocks`? What is `m_methods`? What is `m_methods` and `m_blocks` used for?*

Comment: Some more information would be really good: How is this `m_blocks` initialized? What error message is the compiler giving you?

Comment: That edit doesn't give context at all. Everyone understand that a pointer that is being deallocated with `delete` has been allocated previously with `new`. We need data about your problem, about what are you trying to do.

Comment: Could be a problem with something else writing where it's not supposed to, causing heap corruption.

Comment: You edit includes how you allocated the pointer arrays, but still fails to show how the pointers ***in*** those arrays are allocated. I suspect that is where your problem lies. and potentially, with the failure to properly construct (save) `m_noBlocks` etc.

Comment: @Manu343726 : It is not showing the allocation of the deallocated pointer, but the allocation of m_blocks, which is an array of m_noBlocks pointers to ZFSBlock.

My guess here is that either not all the pointers inside the array are actually pointing to a dynamically allocated ZFSBlock object (thus calling delete on null pointer / garbage memory / stack object) or several elements in the array are in fact pointing to the same address (leading to double deletes).

Comment: @And Note: calling `delete` on a NULL pointer is *not* an error condition (though it *might* be a hint of a larger broken problem). The *indeterminate* pointers are a real problem though. Personally I'm still in Kerrek's camp on this: none of this should be needed if the standard library (`std::vector<>` etc.) were properly being utilized.

Comment: @WhozCraig : Thank you, I forgot about that (yet, as you pointed, it could indicate a bigger design issue).
And I also totally agree that you should always design new code to follow [RAII](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII), for which the STL facilities are golden. But perhaps this is legacy code, and the OP cannot afford such refactoring, so still trying to pinpoint possible problems in the current impl.

Comment: How are the actual pointers assigned to the array elements later allocated?  If they are allocated using e.g. `new ZFSBlock[n]`, then you'll need to use `delete [] m_blocks[blockId]` in the destructor.  (You'll probably also want change the code to use `std::vector<ZFSBlock*>`, to simplify the code.  As it is, you don't free the two arrays you've allocated.)

Comment: @AdN How does RAII apply here?  He's allocating in some function he doesn't show us, and freeing in a completely different function.  (If the types are copyable, of course, he shouldn't be using pointers at all.  A `std::vector<ZFSBlock>` would take care of everything by itself.

Comment: @JamesKanze lol. Whats a little memory leak to a guy trying to solve his loosely related crashing issue? (Of course I'm being sarcastic and your point is excellent, but you already knew that =P). The name of the class suggests he's not all that concerned about much of anything once this thing goes away.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's true, but in that case, why bother deallocating anything:-).

Comment: Have you considered Valgrind? Or perhaps a break-on-write breakpoint for both arrays once you stepped passed their construction in a debugger to catch what is possibly stomping on your memory (potentially, anyway).

Comment: @JamesKanze: You do understand that the solution you offer in order to take care of everything, i.e a std::vector<T>, is the perfect example of an RAII implementation in the STL, where T is the ressource and the container itself is responsible for calling the destructor of each element it contains once destructed ?

Comment: @AdN Do you know what RAII means?  `std::vector` is anything but an RAII class, it has actual behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, std::vector<T> is a container of Ts, T which would be the class managing the resource (eg. a shared_ptr<>). Yet, for RAII to be practical, you need to be able to control the lifetime of a collection of resources, without keeping individual copies of all of them in the current scope... which is one thing the vector is good at.

Answer (score 2):

`m_noBlocks` is left uninitialized, so no one can predict how many pointers you have space to store.

Comment: if it is not a const, but given the lack of info it is as good guess as any :)

Comment: It's possible that it has an in-class member initializer (`int m_noblocks = 50;`), but that seems unlikely.

Comment: A strong guess, I suspect, Ben. I see no mention of it in the constructor except as an r-value, and the preamble is indicative of a member variable. I suspect, as chris pointed out, one familiar with in-class member initialization is unlikely to be doing anything like this in the first place.

Comment: Yup, WhozCraig spotted my rationale for thinking this -- the `m_` prefix suggests a member variable, the constructor would be the place to initialize it, and it isn't doing so.  I consider it pretty likely that some other function is setting `m_noBlocks` and forgetting to resize the two arrays.

Comment: @claptrap : Actually `m_noBlocks` is initialized with some value, which I have not mentioned here, since the constructor is a really big one with lot of other things involved.

Comment: @BenVoigt But of course, in practice, this will give him either a random sized array or an `std::bad_alloc`.  I don't think it's likely to explain the crash in the destructor (unless he sets it later).

Comment: @SathishKrishnan: So what you're saying is that you didn't show real code.

Comment: @BenVoigt True! The actual issue something really complex than assigning value of `m_noBlocks`

Comment: @BenVoigt Any suggestions would you like to make?

Comment: @Satish: You could be writing off the end of one of the object, trashing the allocator data stored next to it, which delete needs.  And the error could be *anywhere* in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that your code is similar to this:

```
class Application
{
private:
    int m_noBlocks;
    struct ZFSBlock
    {
        int a;
    };
    struct ZFSMethods
    {
        int a;
    };
    ZFSBlock **m_blocks;
    ZFSMethods **m_methods;
public:
    Application();
    ~Application();
};

Application::Application()
{
    m_noBlocks = 5;
    m_blocks = new ZFSBlock*[m_noBlocks];
    m_methods = new ZFSMethods*[m_noBlocks];
    for(int i = 0; i < m_noBlocks; i++)
    {
        m_blocks[i] = new ZFSBlock[486]; //random number
        m_methods[i] = new ZFSMethods[156];
    }
}
```

Then you should delete using this:

```
Application::~Application()
{
  for ( int blockId=0; blockId< m_noBlocks; blockId++ ) {
    if ( m_blocks[ blockId ] ) {
      delete [] m_blocks[ blockId ]; //needs "delete []" because I used "new ZFSBlock[486];",
      m_blocks[ blockId ] = NULL;    //not "new ZFSBlock"
    }
    if ( m_methods[ blockId ] ) {
      delete [] m_methods[ blockId ];
      m_methods[ blockId ] = NULL;
    }
  }
  //Also don't forget to delete double pointers:
  if ( m_methods ) {
      delete [] m_methods;
      m_methods = NULL;
    }
  if ( m_methods ) {
      delete [] m_methods;
      m_methods = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: No.  He shouldn't be using pointers at all.  And if he does, there's no need to check for null before deleting, and there's no need to set the pointers to null after deletion (since he won't be able to access them later anyway).

Comment: Actually, you should check for null pointers and set then to null just in case the pointer was not allocated or program decides to call the same destructor twice for some reason, then you would avoid errors.

Comment: Checking for `nullptr` before a `delete` is pointless, and *setting* a pointer to `nullptr` *after* a `delete` is equally-so when the very pointer is a member that is about to be destroyed anyway. Per C++11 § 5.3.5 p2: "... the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer...". This is true both for `delete` and `delete []`.

Comment: I see, but let's say we have destructor called twice, wouldn't it give me an error if I tried to call delete [] on an already deleted pointer? Correct me if I'm wrong, but to avoid it I should set it to NULL before second destructor is called. And thanks, I won't have to check if it's NULL ever again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, these are only guesses, but since guessing is allowed: one
of the pointers in the array wasn't allocated with `new`, or it
was allocated with an array `new` (e.g. something like `new
ZFSBlock[n]`).  Or you could have put the same pointer in twice.

If the objects are copyable, and there is only a single object
in each slot, you should be using `std::vector<ZFSBlock>` and
`std::vector<ZFSMethods>`, rather than an array of pointers.
This will take care of all of the issues, automatically, and
save you a lot of work.  (You might also consider using a single
vector with a struct containing the two elements, if the vector
entries are in a strict one to one relationship.)

If there's more than one object in each slot (i.e. you're using
`new []`, which explains the crash), then the best solution
would be `std::vector<std::vector<ZFSBlock>>` and
`std::vector<std::vector<ZFSMethod>>` (or a single
`std::vector<std::vector<TheStruct>>`).